# Failed to resolve "System.Void Android.Runtime.ResourceDesignerAttribute::.ctor(System.String)" reference from "Mono.Android "

Tags: android, ios, xamarin.ios, xcode9

Using Xcode 8.1 with visual studio 2017 community and Xamarin.iOS Version: 11.12.0.4. I'm connecting windows to Mac.I am getting this error when trying to compile my project:

```
Failed to resolve "System.Void Android.Runtime.ResourceDesignerAttribute::.ctor(System.String)" reference from "Mono.Android, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=84e04ff9cfb79065"
```

This error started appearing when I set 'Link Framework SDKs only' in **Project Options->Build->iOS Build->Linker Behavior -> Link Framework SDKs** only. Before I set it as **"Don't Link"** but it was showing error

```
This version of Xamarin.iOS requires the iOS 9.3 SDK (shipped with Xcode 7.3) when the managed linker is disabled. Either upgrade Xcode, or enable the managed linker.
```

so I followed this [this link](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/64801/after-upgrading-xamarin-to-version-4-1-0-313-getting-error-while-building-ios-project-in-vs2015) . So they suggested me to **upgrade the X code** which I **don't want to do**.And the next option was to set  **'Link Framework SDKs only'** for which I got this error

```
Failed to resolve "System.Void Android.Runtime.ResourceDesignerAttribute::.ctor(System.String)" reference from "Mono.Android, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=84e04ff9cfb79065"
```

How can I solve it?

Comment: If you have an Android project included in the solution and you only want to run the iOS one , close the Android project and try again.

Comment: I have done that as well still the error shows iamlcarus

Comment: check if you had referenced an android library in your ios or pcl project

Comment: Having the same issue here..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this issue by removing the android dll from my IOS project.